# Javascript get li values and encode them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

At the moment I have two (maybe more) unordered lists which are sortable with jquery and ui.

The things that work are that the lists are connected, items are draggable, items can be removed and a form that adds to the list.

What I need however is a function that gets all the content for li items and json encode them ready to be sent off to some db function, or something.

Im new to jquery however and cant find documentation for li items.

Hope Ive explained this well.

Daniel

UPDATE - Sample Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addSortable(value) {
        $("#sortable1").prepend("<li class='ui-state-default' id='"+value+"'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s'></span>"+value+"</li>");
    }

    function deleteItem(value) {
        $("#item-"+value).fadeOut('slow');

        $('#sortable1 li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
        });

        document.getElementById('jsoningreds').innerHTML = text;

    }

    $(function() {
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
        }).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>

    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">

    <li id="item-0" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>8 large chicken thighs, skinned <a href="javascript:deleteItem(0)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>

    <li id="item-1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>seasoned flour (celery salt, cayenne pepper, paprika and white pepper) <a href="javascript:deleteItem(1)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    <li id="item-2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>2 small eggs, beaten <a href="javascript:deleteItem(2)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    <li id="item-3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>100g butter <a href="javascript:deleteItem(3)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <hr />

    <h3>Recipe number 2</h3>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

<li id="item-5" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>3 tsp vegetable oil <a href="javascript:deleteItem(5)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    <li id="item-6" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>1 bay leaf <a href="javascript:deleteItem(6)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    <li id="item-7" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>250g onions, finely sliced <a href="javascript:deleteItem(7)" class="deleteItem"></a></li>
    </ul>

   <p id="jsoningreds">hello</p>
```

Comment: Some example code would help a ton.  You can find all li elements with something like `$('li')`.  Once you have them, the `.each()` method will allow you to iterate over them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [`.sortable('serialize')`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize) - It may solve your problem for you:

> Serializes the sortable's item id's
>   into a form/ajax submittable string.
>   Calling this method produces a hash
>   that can be appended to any url to
>   easily submit a new item order back to
>   the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the
>   id of each item in the format
>   `'setname_number'`, and it spits out a
>   hash like
>   `"setname[]=number&setname[]=number"`.
>
> You can also give in a option hash as
>   second argument to custom define how
>   the function works. The possible
>   options are: `key` (replaces `part1[]`
>   with whatever you want), `attribute`
>   (test another attribute than `id`) and
>   `expression` (use your own regexp).
>
> If serialize returns an empty string,
>   make sure the id attributes include an
>   underscore. They must be in the form:
>   `"set_number"` For example, a 3 element
>   list with id attributes `foo_1`, `foo_5`,
>   `foo_2` will serialize to
>   `foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2`. You can use
>   an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to
>   separate the set and number. For
>   example `foo=1` or `foo-1` or `foo_1` all
>   serialize to `foo[]=1`.

If `serialize` does more than you need, `.sortable('toArray')` should return you an array containing the `id`s of each element in the sortable.